# Retrofit: Redirect to LoginActivity if response code is 401

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

How to start `LoginActivity` from the interceptor(non-activity class)? I have tried the code (`Interceptor`) below but not working for me.

Interceptor

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth_token_string)
                        .build();

                Response response =  chain.proceed(newRequest);
                Log.d("MyApp", "Code : "+response.code());
                if (response.code() == 401){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.getContextOfApplication(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();  //Not working
                    return response;
                }

                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        }).build();
```

This is the current solution I'm using, is there any better solution than this? This solution has to keep repeat on every api call.

MainActivity

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    //success
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Token> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why would you launch an `Activity` from an `Interceptor`? `Interceptor`s are only meant to read/modify/block network requests

Comment: I want to redirect user to LoginActivity if response 401, so I don't have to keep repeat the same code over again for each api call. any better idea?

Comment: you might create an implementation of `Callback` that performs a check on the response status code and, in case of a 401, triggers some logic to launch the LoginActivity

Comment: Where are you making this retrofit class call? Is it inside an activity or a presenter of some kind?

Comment: If the network call was started from within the context of an activity, you can probably use Intent to start the Activity (If I am not too rusty)

Answer (score 24):

Personally, I would like to suggest using event bus pattern here. You can use [greenrobot implementation](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or whatever you want, since it's more about an architecture approach rather than concrete implementation.

1. Create event model

   ```
   public class UnauthorizedEvent {

       private static final UnauthorizedEvent INSTANCE = new UnauthorizedEvent();

       public static UnauthorizedEvent instance() {
           return INSTANCE;
       }

       private UnauthorizedEvent() {
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement custom `Interceptor` which disptaches event about unauthorized reqeusts

   ```
   class UnauthorizedInterceptor implements Interceptor {

       @Override
       public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
           Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
           if (response.code() == 401) {
               EventBus.getDefault().post(UnauthorizedEvent.instance());
           }
           return response;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create `BaseActivity` class which handles `UnauthorizedEvent`

   ```
   public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
       public void onStart() {
           super.onStart();
           EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void onStop() {
           super.onStop();
           EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
       }

       @Subscribe
       public final void onUnauthorizedEvent(UnauthorizedEvent e) {
           handleUnauthorizedEvent();
       }

       protected void handleUnauthorizedEvent() {
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Prevent launching `LoginActivity` from `LoginActivity`

   ```
   public class LoginActivty extends BaseActivity {

       @Override
       protected void handleUnauthorizedEvent() {
           //Don't handle unauthorized event
       }
   }
   ```

   Another approach is to not extending `BaseActivity` here.
5. Register your interceptor

   ```
   OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
           .addInterceptor(new UnauthorizedInterceptor())
           .build();
   ```

Pros:

- Loose coupling between components
- Easaly extending the logic by overriding `handleUnauthorizedEvent`
- No need to rewrite code to use new types of callbacks
- Reduce human factor about making mistakes (using `Callback` instead of `BaseCallback`)

Cons:

- EventBus pattern makes debugging more complicated
- One more dependency or own implementation which brings new code to the project

Also, please take into account, that this example doesn't cover multithreading issues. It solves your problem of handling unauthorized requests. Thus, if two requests receive 401 than it is possible that 2 instances of `LoginActivity` is started.

Comment: Great, maybe rather than event bus, we can use observable (live data) . That should make message passing more easy .

Answer (score 16):

Consider introducing a custom implementation of `retrofit2.Callback` interface, e.g. `BaseCallback`:

```
public abstract class BaseCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private final Context context;

    public BaseCallback(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        if (response.code() == 401) {
            // launch login activity using `this.context`
        } else {
            onSuccess(response.body());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {

    }

    abstract void onSuccess(T response);

}
```

Now, from the caller site you should change `new Callback<Token>` with `new BaseCallback<Token>`:

```
call.enqueue(new BaseCallback<Token>(context) {
    @Override
    void onSuccess(Token response) {
        // do something with token
    }
});
```

Although, this approach doesn't fulfil your following statement:

> so I don't have to keep repeat the same code over again for each api call

nevertheless, I cannot come up with a better approach.

Comment: he asks specifically for response code 401 not every 4XX response code

Comment: while this might work, it's not a good solution. A Callback has no business launching activities

Comment: @TimCastelijns, any better suggestions sir?

Comment: @TimCasteljins, isn't that the approach, that OP tries to refrain from?

Comment: likely, but I don't see how this is any better. Also you left out a quite important part `// launch login activity` how would you go about doing this?

Comment: Good point.`BaseCallback` has to accept a `Context` in constructor. Will apply an edit. Thanks.

Comment: `but I don't see how this is any better`DRY, no code duplication, that's the benefit.

Comment: While this might solve the problem for some cases, you'll still need to duplicate the code to cover synchronous API calls.

Comment: @SpaceBison, what do you mean by *"synchronous API calls"*?

Comment: How are you instantiating an abstract class?

Answer (score 5):

This is how interceptor worked for handling 401 globally

```
public class ResponseHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {
private final Context context;

public ResponseHeaderInterceptor(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@NotNull
@Override
public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    if(response.code() == 401){
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES, 0);
        String userName = pref.getString("key_user_email", "");
        //clear shared preferences
        pref.edit().clear().apply();
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("user", userName);
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).logEvent(Constants.USER_UNAUTHORIZED_EVENT, params);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, IntroActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    return response;
}
```

}

**adding to okhttp client of retrofit**

```
var okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(ResponseHeaderInterceptor(MyApplication.getMyApplicationContext()))//Header interceptor for logging network responses
            .build()
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
    val client: Retrofit?
        get() {
            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.SERVER)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build()
            }
            return retrofit
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to inject activity context in Interceptor instance.
If you are using some DI tools, like Dagger2 or Toothpick it will be very simple. I recommend to use toothpick)

https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick

The most code near by will be in kotlin, because it's my boilerplate code. Those thinks, that you are need to solve your problem i will write in Java.

The solution will be like this:

```
@Qualifier
annotation class BackendUrl


class ActivityModule(activity: BaseActivity): Module() {

    init {
        bind(Activity::class.java).toInstance(activity)
    }

}

class NetworkModule: Module() {

    init {
        bind(String::class.java).withName(BackendUrl::class.java).toInstance(Constants.URL)
        bind(Gson::class.java).toInstance(GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create())
        bind(CacheHolder::class.java).toProvider(CacheProvider::class.java).singletonInScope()
        bind(OkHttpClient::class.java).toProvider(OkHttpProvider::class.java).instancesInScope()
        bind(BackendApi::class.java).toProvider(BackendApiProvider::class.java).instancesInScope()
        bind(RedirectInterceptor::class.java).to(RedirectInterceptor::class.java)
    }

}
```

Than you need to create **Providers** for injection dependency

```
class BackendApiProvider @Inject constructor(
        private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        private val gson: Gson,
        @BackendUrl private val serverPath: String
) : Provider<BackendApi> {

    override fun get() =
            Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .baseUrl(serverPath)
                    .build()
                    .create(BackendApi::class.java)
}
```

And your redirect interceptor:

```
public class RedirectInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final Context context;

    @Inject
    public RedirectInterceptor(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .build();

        Response response =  chain.proceed(newRequest);
        Log.d("MyApp", "Code : "+response.code());
        if (response.code() == 401){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            ((Activity) context).finish();
            return response;
        }

        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
}
```

Oh, yes. For Authorization header will be better to create new instance of another interceptor

```
class HeaderInterceptor(private val token: String?) : Interceptor {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val newRequest =  request.newBuilder()

        Log.d(TAG, "token: $token")

        if (token != null && token.isNotBlank()) {
            newRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
        }

        return chain.proceed(newRequest.build())
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = HeaderInterceptor::class.java.toString()
    }

}
```

And your OkhttpProvder

```
class OkHttpProvider @Inject constructor(cacheHolder: CacheHolder, prefs: IPreferences, redirectInterceptor: RedirectInterceptor) : Provider<OkHttpClient> {

    private val client: OkHttpClient

    init {

        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder
                .addNetworkInterceptor(redirectInterceptor)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor(prefs.getAuthToken()))
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .cache(cacheHolder.okHttpCache)

        client = builder.build()
    }

    override fun get() = client
}
```

Thats all! Now, you just only need to place you modules in right scopes.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.init_view)      

        Toothpick.openScopes("activity scope").apply {
            installModules(ActivityModule(this@YourActivity))
            Toothpick.inject(this@YourActivity, this)
        }

        Toothpick.openScopes("activity scope", "network scope").apply {
            installModules(NetworkModule())
        }

        // your activity code
    }
```

Comment: Why the `((Activity) context).finish();` ?

Comment: Better use some EvenBus-like architecture than "injecting" your UI related tasks into network-layer

Answer (score 2):

**Generalized Solution:**
You can solve it by generalizing the error handling. You can use custom CallAdapterFactory to the Retrofit builder. Please refer below classes :

**RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory :**

```
public class RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory extends CallAdapter.Factory {
    private static Context mContext = null;
    private final RxJava2CallAdapterFactory original;

    private RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory() {
        original = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create();
    }

    public static CallAdapter.Factory create(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        return new RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public CallAdapter<?, ?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new RxCallAdapterWrapper(retrofit, original.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit));
    }

    private static class RxCallAdapterWrapper<R> implements CallAdapter<R, Object> {
        private final Retrofit retrofit;
        private final CallAdapter<R,
                Object> wrapped;

        public RxCallAdapterWrapper(Retrofit retrofit, CallAdapter<R, Object> wrapped) {
            this.retrofit = retrofit;
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
        }

        @Override
        public Type responseType() {
            return wrapped.responseType();
        }

        @Override
        public Object adapt(Call<R> call) {
            Object result = wrapped.adapt(call);
            if (result instanceof Single) {
                return ((Single) result).onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, SingleSource>() {
                    @Override
                    public SingleSource apply(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        return Single.error(asRetrofitException(throwable));
                    }
                });
            }
            if (result instanceof Observable) {
                return ((Observable) result).onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource apply(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        return Observable.error(asRetrofitException(throwable));
                    }
                });
            }
            if (result instanceof Completable) {
                return ((Completable) result).onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, CompletableSource>() {
                    @Override
                    public CompletableSource apply(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        return Completable.error(asRetrofitException(throwable));
                    }
                });
            }
            return result;
        }

        private RetrofitException asRetrofitException(Throwable throwable) {
            // We had non-200 http error
            Log.v("log", "eror");
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                HttpException httpException = (HttpException) throwable;
                final Response response = httpException.response();


                //if ((mContext instanceof Activity)) {

                String s = "Something went wrong."; //mContext.getString(R.string.something_went_wrong);
                try {
                    s = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string()).getString("message");
                    if (response.code() == 401) { // 401 Unauthorized
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return RetrofitException.unexpectedError(s, response, retrofit);

                //showErrorDialog(mContext, response);
                //}

//                return RetrofitException.httpError(response.errorBody().toString(), response, retrofit);
            }
            // A network error happened
            if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
                return RetrofitException.networkError((IOException) throwable);
            }
            // We don't know what happened. We need to simply convert to an unknown error
            return RetrofitException.unexpectedError(throwable);
        }
    }
}
```

**RetrofitException :**

```
public class RetrofitException extends RuntimeException {
    private final String url;
    private final Response response;
    private final Kind kind;
    private final Retrofit retrofit;

    RetrofitException(String message, String url, Response response, Kind kind, Throwable exception, Retrofit retrofit) {
        super(message, exception);
        this.url = url;
        this.response = response;
        this.kind = kind;
        this.retrofit = retrofit;
    }

    public static RetrofitException httpError(String url, Response response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        String message = response.code() + " " + response.message();
        return new RetrofitException(message, url, response, Kind.HTTP, null, retrofit);
    }

    public static RetrofitException networkError(IOException exception) {
        return new RetrofitException(exception.getMessage(), null, null, Kind.NETWORK, exception, null);
    }

    public static RetrofitException unexpectedError(Throwable exception) {
        return new RetrofitException(exception.getMessage(), null, null, Kind.UNEXPECTED, exception, null);
    }

    public static RetrofitException unexpectedError(String s, Response response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new RetrofitException(s, null, null, Kind.UNEXPECTED, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * The request URL which produced the error.
     */
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * Response object containing status code, headers, body, etc.
     */
    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    /**
     * The event kind which triggered this error.
     */
    public Kind getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    /**
     * The Retrofit this request was executed on
     */
    public Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return retrofit;
    }

    /**
     * HTTP response body converted to specified {@code type}. {@code null} if there is no
     * response.
     *
     * @throws IOException if unable to convert the body to the specified {@code type}.
     */
    public <T> T getErrorBodyAs(Class<T> type) throws IOException {
        if (response == null || response.errorBody() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Converter<ResponseBody, T> converter = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(type, new Annotation[0]);
        return converter.convert(response.errorBody());
    }

    /**
     * Identifies the event kind which triggered a {@link RetrofitException}.
     */
    public enum Kind {
        /**
         * An {@link IOException} occurred while communicating to the server.
         */
        NETWORK,
        /**
         * A non-200 HTTP status code was received from the server.
         */
        HTTP,
        /**
         * An internal error occurred while attempting to execute a request. It is best practice to
         * re-throw this exception so your application crashes.
         */
        UNEXPECTED
    }
}
```

**Retrofit Builder :**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory.create(context))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

You can handle `401` in `RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory` and other errors through `Throwable`.

Comment: maybe open source this as a library?