# What is the correct way to handle UnAuthenticated response (401) in Android retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, http-status-code-401

I want to take the user to the login screen whenever I encounter a 401 response from the server.

I am currently handling 401 like this:

```
public abstract class BaseCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private final Context context;

    public BaseCallback(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        if (response.code() == 401) {
            // launch login activity using `this.context`
        } else {
            onSuccess(response.body());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {

    }

    abstract void onSuccess(T response);

}
```

Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/49789543/6341943

But this way, I have to pass context from my ViewModel(my ViewModel is inherited from [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel)) whenever I make an API call.

Another way I found was to use an interceptor.

I feel like there should be a better way to handle this but I couldn't find something better than this.

How does Google handle this? I couldn't find any such sample apps. I tried [ioshed](https://github.com/google/iosched) but couldn't find anything like this.

Please point me in the right direction.